# Not getting the concept of COUNT with GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

This is not my job, neither my homework. I'm just self-learnin from Prof. Donatus course on udemy and these are the problems he used in his course.

**Objective 1:**
Your logistics manager wants to know the number of times each ship region appears in the company database. Use SQL query to get the details.

**Objective 2:**
Using the shipregion column, count how many times each value has appeared in the column.

The database: Northwind

The table: orders

[image]

Solution of 1:

```
SELECT ShipRegion,
    COUNT(ShipRegion)
FROM
    orders
GROUP BY ShipRegion;
```

Solution of 2:

```
SELECT ShipRegion,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    orders
GROUP BY ShipRegion;
```

I understand the first solution but not the second solution.

My confusion: How does doing COUNT(*) makes sure to count all shipregions only? Is it because group by shipregion is used?

If that's the case, in above solution, we are also usingg COUNT(shipregion). I don't understand. Please help.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the difference between the two objectives.

Answer (score 5):

The COUNT() function is an aggregate function that returns the number of rows in a table. The COUNT() function allows you to count all rows or only rows that match a specified condition.

The COUNT() function has three forms:

1. `COUNT(*)`,
2. `COUNT(expression)`
3. `COUNT(DISTINCT expression)`

`COUNT(*)` function

The `COUNT(*)` function returns the number of rows in a result set returned by a SELECT statement. The `COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows including duplicate, non-NULL and NULL rows.

`COUNT(expression)`

The `COUNT(expression)` returns the number of rows that do not contain NULL values as the result of the expression.

`COUNT(DISTINCT expression)`

The COUNT(DISTINCT expression) returns the number of distinct rows that do not contain NULL values as the result of the expression.

The return type of the `COUNT()` function is BIGINT. The `COUNT()`  function returns 0 if there is no matching row found.

Consider a simplified example based on your data

```
CREATE TABLE   `orders` (
  `ShipRegion` varchar(6) 
) ;

INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (null),(null),('RJ'),('RJ'),('RJ'),('SP'),('NM'),('NM');
```

Query1,

```
SELECT ShipRegion,
      COUNT(*)
FROM orders
GROUP BY ShipRegion;
```

Result

```
ShipRegion  COUNT(*)
   null       2
   RJ         3
   SP         1
   NM         2
```

Query2,

```
SELECT ShipRegion,
       COUNT( ShipRegion)
FROM  orders
GROUP BY ShipRegion;
```

Result

```
ShipRegion  COUNT( ShipRegion)
    null         0
    RJ           3
    SP           1
    NM           2
```

Query3,

```
SELECT ShipRegion,
       COUNT(distinct ShipRegion)
FROM  orders
GROUP BY ShipRegion;
```

Result

```
ShipRegion  COUNT(distinct ShipRegion)
    null        0
    NM          1
    RJ          1
    SP          1
```

> My confusion: How does doing `COUNT(*)` makes sure to count all
> shipregions only? Is it because group by shipregion is used?

Yes, The `COUNT(*)` function is often used with a `GROUP BY` clause to return the number of elements in each group.

In the first Objective I think you need to apply where shipregion  is not null, because null is not equal to anything

```
SELECT ShipRegion,
      COUNT(*)
FROM orders
WHERE ShipRegion is not null
GROUP BY ShipRegion;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/xEyGMfn5)

Read more on [Counting Rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: `SELECT 
    c.CompanyName, COUNT(o.orderid)
FROM
    customers c
        INNER JOIN
    orders o ON c.customerid = o.customerid
GROUP BY c.CompanyName;` Here we're doing COUNT(expression) but we're not grouping by that expression and it still works, why? How? It's still the northwind database.
https://brucebauer.info/assets/ITEC3610/Northwind/Northwind-Sample-Database-Diagram.pdf

Comment: That's even more confusing to me. Can you explain? If result is based on GROUP BY Clause, why do we need COUNT there up?

Comment: @achhainsan in simple words in your first query you are counting how many  values are per each CompanyName including non null values. If instead of `COUNT(o.orderid)` you use `COUNT(c.CompanyName)` the only diffrence would be that will be counted only non null values. count(1) still counts the all values including nulls . I hope it's more clear.

Comment: still not clear. Actually at this point, I don't know what I don't know. I'll form a question later on and ask in reddit as stackexchange doesn't allow duplicates.